# Is this error a bug in Xcode 7 or swift 2?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging, error-handling

I've been getting this `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11` error for 2 days now, and I cannot wrap my head around why its doing so. The error pointed at a specific query I made to parse.. However to test if it was my code or just a bug, I copied this EXACT block from Parse's query doc into my project as a function:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil {
    // The find succeeded.
    println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
    // Do something with the found objects
    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
      for object in objects {
        println(object.objectId)
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
  }
}
```

And it threw the error once again to that block.. Xcode is has also been throwing this message to my compiler :

[image]

Why is this happening ?

**UPDATE**

so it seems Kevin's answer below cleared the compiler bug by letting the compiler tell me the type rather than specifying it in the `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in` line , by correcting it to :

`query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects, error) -> Void in
}`

however this other block is a little more complex, how do i adjust it to rid the error? :

```
func loadBooks() {

        var query = PFQuery(className: "Books")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
               self.books.removeAll()
               let bookObjects = objects as! [PFObject]
               for (index, object) in enumerate(bookObjects) {
                  self.books.append(Book(pfBook: object))
              }
          }else if let secondMessage = error?.userInfo?["error"] as? String
              where secondMessage == "The Internet connection appears to be offline." {
                    self.failedMessage(secondMessage)
                    self.activityIndicator.hidden = true
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
              }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

                self.collectionView!.reloadData()
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Can you narrow down which line of code is causing the error? See if the first line compiles. If so, check if the second line compiles. Third, etc.

Comment: Definitely a compiler bug.  Swift is new, and it still has some bugs.  Even if your code has actual errors, the complier should output an error message; not crash.

Comment: exactly my sentiments @NobodyNada

Answer (score 1):

`objects` is actually of type `[PFObject]?` not `[AnyObject]?`. A wild guess would say the root cause trying to downcast.

Anyway, just use the correct type to fix this

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
}
```

or just let the compiler tell you the type

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects, error) -> Void in
}
```

Comment: well letting the compiler tell me type stopped the error throwing for that block, but check my updated answer, this is the original block that drew the error, and still is

Comment: Are you saying there a different error in that block?

Comment: no I'm saying the first block i posted in the question wasn't the original block that engaged the error, thats a block straight from parses docs that is similar to my original block. I used it as a test to whether it was an xcode bug calling the error or not.

Comment: now your answer you provided fixed the compiler error for the parse block, but its a slight difference with the block i just posted in my updated question.. how should i fix that one?

Comment: @MikeStrong, you'll need to provide more information. (Ex. What error are you trying to fix, what is the error message, what have you tried). If it is a separate question involving a different issue you should probably ask a new question

Answer (score -1):

```
        let query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")

        query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

            (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                // The find succeeded.

                print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")

                // Do something with the found objects

                print(objects)

                if let objects = objects {

                    for object in objects {

                        print(object.objectId)

                    }

                }

            } else {

                // Log details of the failure

                print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")

            }

        }
```

Try this! It works!